# My dropdown isn't coming down

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

HTML:-

```
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>AIT Project</title>
  </head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign  Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div> 
</nav>
</nav>
</body>
```

I am making a simple bootstrap responsive navbar but the dropdown isn't dropping and showing the content .I am not able to figure out the issue. There are no errors in the console

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure the correct js and css files are loading correctly? (I replaced them with cdn urls.) Why are you loading bootstrap.js twice (minified and unminified)? Could that be a problem?

Comment: I removed it but still its not dropping down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are linking properly to your js files.

Try to add this code in the end of your html file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

if it works it means that you are not properly linking to the bootstrap.min.js file.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. You mean the 3-bar navbar-toggle on the right-hand side?

You have an extraneous space in your data-target attribute. It says `data- target="#myNavbar"` instead of `data-target="#myNavbar"`.

[image: 3-bar drop-down]

*Edit in response to comment:*
So you don't see this drop-down? This is the one that I was initailly looking at when I said that it worked for me.
[image: Last page 1 drop-down]

Try replaced your `<head>` with this code:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>AIT Project</title>
</head>
```

Then it will be exactly the same as the code I'm using. I've replaced the links to local files with links to files from a CDN. That means you'll need to be connected to the internet. Does it work now?

Comment: This responsiveness is proper. The last link "Page1" isn't dropping down.